# How use mocha test framework with node.js and sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, sails.js

I want to use mocha for node.js. The last test framework I used was Rspec from Ruby on Rails so I'm trying to do it in the same way but I get cnfused by the **huge** framework and all the  libraries I could use.

I'm following the official *get started* but it doesn't explains how organize the tests.

http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#installation

Now, I'm reading that I can use the following libraries:

- https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js - Something to test model instances.
- https://github.com/LearnBoost/expect.js - Minimalistic BDD assertion toolkit based on should.js
- http://chaijs.com/ - Looks big, includes should, expect and another lib
- https://github.com/visionmedia/better-assert - Better c-style assertions using callsite for self-documenting failure messages. (I actually don't understand the purpose so far, looks not better than others)
- https://github.com/rjanicek/mocha.js-haxe - Looks to be used browser side, but mocha also said that it's running browser side.

And I know there are more, this is just the list I saw on mocha official website.
For what I can understand, it looks like chai is the one to use with mocha, what do you think about that?

And, so far, I never saw anything to help me to decide where write the tests (okay, in /test/, of course) and how organize everything.

I'm also use the great sails.js framework (based on express) and pomelo.js for different projects, I need to use the same kind of tests on both frameworks, so I'm looking for a general architecture and libraries that I can use on both (so, something not specific to sails.js but usable directly from any other framework)

This is how I plan to organize my tests, do you think that's a correct architecture?
[image]

The main issue with node is that there are a lot of frameworks, plugins, libraries and I dont know what's the best choice, node.js is really huge with a big community and that's really difficult to have an overview of all the possibilities.

How do you deal with your tests?

Comment: For the basic usage of Mocha with Sails see [here](https://github.com/bredikhin/sailsjs-mocha-testing-barrels-fixtures-example).

Answer (score 7):

I found the blog post [Unit Testing Sails.js Applications With Mocha](http://www.tysoncadenhead.com/blog/unit-testing-sails-js-applications-with-mocha#.VEJS3L5fhhw) helpful in regards to setting up and organizing tests.

However, because I'm using Sails version 0.10.5, I decided to clean up the Grunt configuration a bit. I added a file named `mocha.js` in the `tasks/config/` folder with the following code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.config.set('mochaTest', {
      test: {
        options: {
          reporter: 'spec'
        },
        src: ['tests/**/*.spec.js']
      }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');

};
```

I then registered the task by creating a file named `test.js` inside of `tasks/register`. Inside this file, I added the following code.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('test', [
            'mochaTest'
        ]
    );
};
```

You can then run `grunt test` to see the results.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file named test.js inside your test folder

for testing assertion best option is something like chai or should or expect, for testing rest api or sending http request you can use supertest. At first include all the library inside the test file

```
"use strict"
var should = require('should');
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require('supertest');
```

Now for business logic testing include the file you need. Say I have a file named LoginService inside api/services you can include it by following

```
var loginService = require('../api/services/LoginService');
```

Now you can start testing your test block will look like something similar

```
describe('Sample Test', function(){
    var url = "http://localhost:1337/";
    before(function(done){
        //Anything that needed to be done before executing;
        done();
    });

     it("Should test rest api", function(done){
        var email = {'email':'sample@email.com'};
             //Calling rest api with email as a part of req body
         request(url)
        .post('api/v1/email/isvalid')
        .send(email)
        // end handles the response
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
                    // Check response
            res.should.have.status(200) ;
            done();
        });
    });

    it("Should test business logic", function(done){
        loginService.someFunction(someParameter, function callback(data){
            //do your logic test here
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be the usual advice.  But what about organizing a project where you actually have some tests, rather than just one test file?

Comment: A good practice will be to have one file of the same name + postfix for every file you have in your source folder, under a cloned folder tree, containing tests for that source file